# Word VBA - Auto Recovery calls DocumentBeforeSave event

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word VBA I have a call named Events with following code in it:

```
Public WithEvents EventSource As Word.Application

Private Sub EventSource_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If oScript.DocType = diDocTypeScript Then

    WriteToTextLog " SaveAsUI = " & CStr(SaveAsUI) & "Path= " & Doc.Path & " Name= " & Doc.Name
    If SaveAsUI Then
        Call Me.SaveAsBox(Doc)
    Else
        oScript.DlgTimeLastSaved = Now()
        Doc.Save
        If oDlgApplication.DevelopMode Then MsgBox "Saving Document: " & Doc.FullName
    End If

    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

**Now the problem is, when the Auto-Recovery triggers, this save method is called automatically and it saves the actual file instead of saving a backup version of the file to use in case Word crashes.**

So is there a way to identify auto-save (recovery) and keep it as it is?

Thanks,
Tejas

Comment: BTW, what is the reason to keep this event? It doesn't make sense in this situation. Or is there some other code inside the Sub? Or the original idea was to do exactly what you are going to remove...

Comment: @KazJaw I am doing some checking on my document before the save event. So I really need to take control of that.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I mean... so, this event code which you show in question, is it complete? Show the complete event code, please.

Comment: @KazJaw Please check the full node now. Thnx

Comment: which office version do you have? Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @KazJaw I am using 2010 but I am facing this issue in all versions office.

Comment: I can't repeat your problem on my Office 2013. In my opinion Autorecovery doesn't trigger the event `DocumentBeforeSave`. But it could be triggered by other macro, please check it.